# Unity2D: Limit the travel distance of my player to half the size of the cameras width

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, limit, distance

I'm having troubles trying to limit the distance of my player from leaving a certain area, I want to shorten the distance to half the width of my main camera, is there a way to do so, this is my code:

**UPDATED EDIT:**

```
void Update () {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
                if (EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject)
                    return;
                Vector3 mousePosition = Input.mousePosition - target;
                mousePosition.z = 10;
                target = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (mousePosition);
                target.y = transform.position.y;


            } 
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, target, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: please reduce the code so that only the relevant code is present and describe your problem more in details - what happens currently and how does the current behavior differ from the desired one?

Comment: What part of this code works/doesn't work? Expected output of it vs real output? You're gonna have to give us more to work with here.

Comment: Sorry, I'll shorten the code!